# Are all eBooks in the iBookstore DRM protected?

Tags: ebook, drm, books

A few weeks ago I bought a book in the iBookstore. The title of this book is "Der Aurora Effekt" (German). Then a few weeks later I bought the book "The Tributes of Panem" (German version).

The first title I can copy to my Kobo eBook reader and read the book. But "The Tributes of Panem" was not readable!

Is it possible that not all books are DRM protected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes.

(Not all books are DRM protected.)

Per the **[official iBooks FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4059)**...

> #### How can I determine which books are copy-protected (DRM) versus those that are DRM-free?
>
> iTunes can show you the kind of book you have by selecting the book and then choosing *File > Get Info*.
>
> - If the Kind is marked as **Book**, this is a book you **downloaded** from the Internet.
> - If it is listed as **Purchased Book**, it is a **DRM-free** book downloaded from the iBookstore.
> - If it is listed as **Protected Book**, it is a **copy-protected** book from the iBookstore.

Only "protected books" have DRM protection.

Comment: Just a note: This section is no longer present in the linked FAQ as of 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a book in the iBookstore has DRM is up to the publisher.  Two publishers I know of never do DRM, O'Reilly and Take Control, and there are others too.